# Why is a Parah Aduma kodesh with קדושת בדק הבית?

Tags: halacha, parah-adumah, kodshim

See Gemara in [Yuma 42a](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.42a.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [Rambam Hilchos Parah 1:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Red_Heifer.1.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

If it's a korban, then it should have full kdushas korban, and if it's not, then why isn't it completely chullin?

Comment: If it had full *kedushas korban* it would be *shechutei chutz*?

Answer (score 1):

Kedushas Bedek Habayis applies to everything that is the property of the Temple, even [bricks and stones](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Meilah.5?lang=he). So naturally the parah adumah [is also kodshei bedek habayis](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Trespass.2?lang=he&p2=Even_Ha%27azel_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_Trespass.2.5&lang2=he&p3=Bekhorot.25a.10&lang3=he&w3=Rashi&lang4=he), because it is the property of the Temple.